# Using a variable as column name in a MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I made a table for appointments that works as a form, it shows whether a time slot is free or not and you can reserve appointments from it. 
This is the code that works ..

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM days "); 
echo " <form action=\"change.php\" method=\"post\"><TABLE>";
echo "<TR><Th> Dia <Th> 8 <Th> 9 <Th> 10 <Th> 11<Th>12 <Th> 13 <Th> 14 <Th> 15 <Th> 16       ";

while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    if ($rows['08'] == 'taken') {
        $rows['08'] = "<TD id=\"red\" >TAKEN";
    } 
    else {
        $rows['08'] = "<TD id=\"blue\" ><input type=\"radio\" name=\"slot\" value= \"08 $rows[day]\" >$rows[08]";
    }

    if ($rows['09']=='taken') {
        $rows['09']="<TD  id=\"red\" >TAKEN";
    }
    else {
        $rows['09']="<TD  id=\"blue\" ><input type=\"radio\" name=\"slot\" value= \"09 $rows[day]\" >$rows[09]";
    }

    if ($rows['10']=='taken') {
        $rows['10']="<TD  id=\"red\" >TAKEN";
    }
```

the code goes further to cover all timeslots ..
this is an example of how the table looks like .. well ..with the free cells having a radio  botton next to them:

```
           day   08      09     10     11     12     13     14     15      16 
    2013-05-05  free   free   free   taken   free   free   taken   free   free
```

what i'm trying to do is to automate this . as in creating a loop so i dont have to repeat the same code so many times ..
i tried the following but it didnt work:

```
while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $c="08"; 
    if ($rows["$c"]=='taken') {
        $rows["$c"]='taken';
    } 

    if ($rows["$c"]=='free') {
        $rows[$c] = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"slot\" value= \"$c. $rows[day]\" >$rows[$c]";
    }

    echo "<TR><TD>$rows[day]"; echo "<TD> $rows[$c]"; $c++;
    echo "<TD> $rows[$c]"; $c++;
    echo "<TD> $rows[$c]"; $c++;
    echo "<TD> $rows[$c]"; $c++;
```

.....and so on ..

I'm thinking the problem is in the way to put the variable inside the row array 
any suggestions?

Comment: Closing tags is always nice, though not required.

Comment: That is true ..but the question here is about trying to use a variable as a column name ..

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert but can't you do `echo "<TD>".$rows[$c]."</TD>";` since `.` is the concatenation character in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM days "); 
echo "<form action='change.php' method='post'><table>";
echo "<tr><td>day</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td></tr>";

while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

    while (  $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {

        $res[]="<tr><td>".$rows[day];

        for ($c="8";$c<="16";$c++)
        {

            if ($c<10){$ca="0".$c;} else {$ca=$c;}

            if ($rows[$ca]=='taken') {
                $res[]='taken';
            } 
            if ($rows[$ca]=='free') {
                $res[] = "<input type='radio' name='slot' value='".$c." ".$rows[day]." >".$rows[$ca];
            }
        }
        $res[]="</td></tr>";
        echo implode("</td><td>",$res);
    }
    echo "</table></form>";
```

Comment: this doesnt work because it only echos the first column, i need to show the contents of all my columns which are (08-09-10-11-12-13-14-15-16) representing the opening hours

Comment: oh, sorry, it must be in line, not vertical?

Comment: please show your table structure, and write exaple whitch you want get, thanks

Comment: yes .. in the table each row is a day ..while the hours(timeslots ) are columns ...and this is how my database is constructed too

Comment: i have edited the question adding a row of how my table looks like

Comment: It worked .. i had to change somethings to suit the structure i had which i find weird because the use of ' and " is always delt with differently in my server than in the examples given here .but the key is in the (for) statement .thank you very much.